# How to register Concrete Class to Generic Interface?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I try to register concrete class that is based on generic class, and this generic class is based on generic interface. The problem is how to do this in Castle Windsor and ASP.NET Boilerplate such that I don't need many code that register it one by one.

```
public interface IService<T> where T: class ...

public class Service<T, TE, TPrimary> : IService<T> where T: class ...

public class ConcreteService : Service<SomeType, SomeType2, string> ...
public class AnotherConcreteService : Service<AnotherSomeType, AnotherSomeType2, string> ...
```

With such structure, I would like to register to `IService<SomeType>` the class `ConcreteService`, which implements this service. How could I do that with Castle Windsor? Implementation one by one looks like this:

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IQueryService<SomeType>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(ConcreteService)).Named("ConcreteTest"));

IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IQueryService<AnotherSomeType>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(AnotherConcreteService)).Named("AnotherConcreteTest"));
```

Usage that I would like to have:

```
var test1 = IocContainer.Resolve<IQueryService<SomeType>(); // Here should be ConcreteService
var test2 = IocContainer.Resolve<IQueryService<AnotherSomeType>(); // Here should be AnotherConcreteService
```

With line by line approach, it works, but how to register all based on `IQueryService<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. `IQueryService<SomeTypeDto>`

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.IGenerics.IQueryService`1[[AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.SomeEntitiesDto.SomeTypeDto, AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] was found

To register concrete classes to the generic interface, use `.WithService.Base()`.

For compatibility<sup>1</sup> with `RegisterAssemblyByConvention`, configure a unique name.

```cs
public override void Initialize()
{
    var thisAssembly = ...

    IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(thisAssembly);

    IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Classes.FromAssembly(thisAssembly)
            .BasedOn(typeof(IQueryService<>))
            .WithService.Base()
            .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())) // Add this
    );

    // ...
}
```

<sup>1</sup> If your concrete class implements ASP.NET Boilerplate's `ITransientDependency`, then the default name is used to register the class for `.WithService.Self()` inside `RegisterAssemblyByConvention`.

## 2. `IRepository<SomeType>`

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component 'AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.SomeEntityService.SomeTypeService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.SomeEntityService.SomeTypeService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.SomeEntities.SomeType, AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

To use ASP.NET Boilerplate repositories, define a **public** DbSet.

```cs
public class AbpProjectNameDbContext : ...
{
    /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */

    // DbSet<SomeType> SomeEntities { get; set; }     // Remove this
    public DbSet<SomeType> SomeEntities { get; set; } // Add this

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to register all the various implementations of the generic `IQueryService<T>` in one expression you're most likely after something like this

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromThisAssembly()
      .BasedOn(typeof(IQueryService<>))
      .WithServiceBase()
);
```

I strongly recommend spending some time with [the documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#base) that explores all the variants

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to spend some time with the documentation to make sure you're comfortable with the API and usage patterns of an IoC container, and to help you avoid common problems. See https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/faq.md, https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/three-calls-pattern.md and https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/ioc.md in particular

Comment: @CrazyBaran Which dependencies?

Comment: @CrazyBaran Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: @aaron You can find repro project here https://github.com/CrazyBaran/module-zero-core-template

Comment: @aaron I refactor project. Check now. It was in controllers IQuery<SomeEntityDto> in constructor. Right now is IQuery<SomeTypeDto>. It is implemented by SomeTypeService in application layer. Interface is in IGenerics.